# problem changing recordtype

Tags: workflow, record-type

I have the requirement that when a Lead is set to "Closed-not converted", the annual revenue field should be set to read-only.

I tried creating 2 page layouts and 2 record types and written a workflow that would update the recordtype once the lead status changes to this status but it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things on this one.

You don't need a trigger to change a record type. 
A workflow + field update of the recordtype should just work fine.

I tested your exact scenario and this should just work.

A couple of things you should want to check:

- check that your record type is available to your users
- if you are testing this as an admin, remember that fields marked as read only on the page layout, you are still able to edit those as an admin
- try by adding the lead record type field to your page layouts to be 100% sure of the current record type of your record

If that still doesn't work, I suggest that you post a screenshot of your workflow rule + your workflow action(s).

Answer (score 0):

> object must not be edited

If I were you I use validation rule for this job :)

```
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(LeadStatus), "closed- not converted")
```

This is simple solution and easier to manage

Ps. Isn't then better solution to just lock record?
For example in approval process?

Comment: Hi annual revenue field must become readonly

Comment: When anything cant be changed then all fields are read-only :)
But If you want to allow change other fields then you have to either use 2 layouts and 2 recordtypes (which could be hard to manage in future) or Visual Force page (which is too much work to just block one field)